# Как удалить не нужные символы из результата парсера

Tags: php, веб-программирование, curl

```
<?php
function browser($url) {

$url="http://";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3");
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $html;
}

preg_match_all('~{"lat":"(.*?)","address~is', browser($url), $text2);
?>

<?print implode('</br>', array_slice($text2[1], 0, 20)) ;?>
```

Парсер парсит текст такого вида:

```
41.51078112096761","lng":"2.3593415557699737
```

А нужно получить такой вид:

```
41.51078112096761,2.3593415557699737
```

Comment: Очевидно, что пора узнать, что на свете есть __json__.

Comment: Можно воспользоватся функцией `str_replace` например: `str_replace('","lng":"', ',', '41.51078112096761","lng":"2.3593415557699737');` получите `41.51078112096761,2.3593415557699737`

Comment: Мне нужно исключить из парсинга "lng":" что бы парсилось только запитая и цифры, подскажите, как правильно в код добавить это свойство str_replace( пробую не получается :(

Comment: В целом вам нужно доработать регулярное выражение `'~{"lat":"(.*?)","address~is'`. И не помешало бы чтобы был пример того что возвращает функция `browser($url)`.

Comment: Прочитай уже про json.

Comment: А вы можете скинуть мне готовое решение ?, я просто не программист, я не селен в этом, смог только понять как спарсить часть когда, а как исключить не нужное, понять не могу, если конечно вам не трудно помочь.

Comment: Что приходит в $html? Такое чувство, что там нормальный человеческий json. Если да, то не нужно лишних телодвижений для парсинга. Приведите пример. Если мои догадки верны, то вот это поможет: ```$json = json_decode($html, true); $str = $json["lng"].",".$json["lat"];```

Comment: @Crasher Я вставил приведенный вами код в парсер, не чего не изменилось, возможно я просто не правильно что то сделал, парсер парсит информацию отсюда https://ads.pontogram.com/order.php, моя цель что бы получилась формировать такие строки `new google.maps.LatLng( 41.51078112096761,2.3593415557699737),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так получается

```
$str = file_get_contents("https://ads.pontogram.com/order.php");
preg_match_all("/\{(.+?)\}/", $str, $result);

foreach($result[0] as $matches) {
    $tmp = json_decode($matches, true);
    echo $tmp["lat"].",".$tmp["lng"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Благодарю! Все работает, скажите, а как результат поместить в это `new google.maps.LatLng(....), ` как это было сделано с тегом <br>

Comment: Догадался сам )))) очень мне помогли!